# Laravel / Php function behavior

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Is there a way to pass the information obtained in a Request function to an included page?  Consider the following situation - code below works as expected

```
public function myFunction(Request $request){

   $validator = \Validator::make($request::all(), [
      'myField'  => 'Required',
   ]);

}
```

But what I want to do this

```
public function myFunction(Request $request){

    include(app_path() . '/myfunction/validateThis.php')

}
```

Where the above file named validateThis.php has the validator code inside?  Is there a way to get this (Request $request) variable passed through to the include? It returns null right now and I'm not sure if there is a workaround or not

Comment: Hi, you have an error here `include(app_path() . '/myfunction/validateThis.php'))` the last `)` is useless.

Comment: fixed it wasnt that way in my own file so it wasnt the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the validateThis.php has been included, all you need to do is pass the request object to the function that handles the validation.

1. Include file that has the validate function
   `include 'validateThis.php'`
2. call function with the request object passed to it
   `validate($request)`

Answer (score 0):

Create a global variable to save the `$request` data. Then use `global <variable>` in your function inside the included file.

Comment: Hi, the included file inherits the scope of the parent file, so `$request` should be directly accessible.

Comment: Its not as simple as that due to the Request $request.  I was able to save, and pass the contents of $request but when issuing the \Validator::make($request::all()... portion, its looking for a class and not a variable.

Comment: It depends on how the include file is used. If it's code that gets inserted into the current function, then yes. But, if the included code has it's own class, function, etc, then the scope doesn't matter.

Comment: To add to that, given the fact that the included file is 'only' included and nothing in it is called thereafter, the include should only be direct code.

Comment: It would help to see the code sample of the included file.

Comment: The code inside the include is what I show above in the first example but extracted into a file.